# Angular Application Deployment IIS Automation like using Docker/Jenkins etc

Tags: angular, iis, devops, build-automation, angular10

I am deploying angular application in IIS server manually like copying the build from my system to particular IIS server location.

My code is maintained in TFS repository.

Backend for my application is Mulesoft and Mulesoft is deployed in cloudhub and front end will be deployed to IIS.

I need to know do we have any file so I can configure my steps so once I do run it will build automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Angular CLI to automate your development workflow:

- create a new Angular application
- run a development server with Live Reload support to preview your application during development
- add features to your existing Angular application
- run your application’s unit tests
- run your application’s end-to-end (E2E) tests
- build your application for deployment to production.

To start up your Angular application with the Angular CLI, you simply run the following command from the command window from inside the root folder of your project:

```
ng serve
```

After executing this command you can navigate to http://localhost:4200 to start your application in your browser. The Angular CLI comes with the Webpack bundling tool and uses Webpack to compile, build and bundle all the TypeScript code and starts a Webpack development web server that runs and listens to requests on port 4200 by default.

Of course, the real power of the Angular CLI is its support for live reloading of your application. While still running, the Webpack process is actively watching the src folder for file changes. When a file change is detected the application is automatically rebuilt and reloaded in the browser.

refer this below link for more detail:

[Angular 2 continuous deployment with jenkins and seperate production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740250/angular-2-continuous-deployment-with-jenkins-and-seperate-production-server)

Comment: I am building the project using "ng build" and pasting the files in IIS server. So,I need to know automation deployment to IIS server for angular application once i added the code to TFS respository